# ref.getDownloadURL is null while uploading, how to wait before put it into other variable

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload an image to firebase storage and then put the download URL in the firebase cloud firestore, but the value in the database is always null

```
File image;
String imageUrl;

...

  Future<Null> uploadImage() async {
    if (image == null) {
      imageUrl = defaultImage;
    } else {
      StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(filename);
      uploadTask = ref.putFile(image);

      imageUrl = await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
    }
  }

  void _addData() {
    Firestore.instance.collection('kajian').add({
      "imageUrl": imageUrl,
    });
    image = null;
    imageUrl = null;
  }

...

      Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            uploadImage();
            _addData();
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.cloud_upload),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The download URL can only be determined after the image upload has completed. So you'll have to write it to the database, after the upload is complete.

```
Future<Null> uploadImage() async {
  StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(filename);

  uploadTask = ref.putFile(image);

  String imageUrl = await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();

  Firestore.instance.collection('kajian').add({
    "imageUrl": imageUrl,
  });
}
```